# ReactionRoles does not work after restart

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made this reactionrole command for my discord server, and it works great. Only problem is that whenever i restart the bot, it does not read the reactions of that old message, and i need to always send new reactionrole message.

So i want it to work even after restart. (It does not need to give roles to people who have reacts while the bot is online.)

My code:

````
module.exports = {
    name: 'age',
    description: "Sends Embed with reactionrole!",
    async execute( kaoru, message, args, Discord) {

        if (message.member.roles.cache.has('926200778841030666')){
        const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
        


        //Define roles and emojis
        const thirteen =  message.guild.roles.cache.get("939772491558187049");
        const sixteen = message.guild.roles.cache.get("939772759624548362");
        const legal = message.guild.roles.cache.get("939772853014888538");
        const pedo   = message.guild.roles.cache.get("939773034032685127");


        const emoji1 = '<:bluee:960111931572768769>';
        const emoji2 = '<:pinkk:960111867462836255>';
        const emoji3 = '<:yelloww:960111822499885057>';
        const emoji4 = '<:greenn:960111905278668811>';
       

        
        const p = '<:pink_arrow:926036002915647538>';

        //Embed
        
            let embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#FF6BDB")
                .setTitle(" <:pink_sakura:926036002932416542> Tell us your age <:pink_sakura:926036002932416542> ")
                .setThumbnail('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/925777263767724052/960113516700901438/awdawdawd.png?width=818&height=663')
                .addFields(
                    
                    {   name:"━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━_ _ _ _",
                        value: ` **
${emoji1} ${p} 13-15
${emoji2} ${p} 16-18
${emoji3} ${p} 18-21
${emoji4} ${p} 21+ **`,
                    },

                
                        
                   
                )
                .setImage('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/926031400551981056/939796016536895488/dividerrr.gif')
                


        //sends embed and reacts

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
            .then(m => {
                m.react(`${emoji1}`);
                m.react(`${emoji2}`);
                m.react(`${emoji3}`);
                m.react(`${emoji4}`);
             });
            
            
    
      
     //Gives roles
     kaoru.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

        
            if (reaction.emoji.name === 'bluee') {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(thirteen)
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === 'pinkk') {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(sixteen)
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === 'yelloww') {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(legal)
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === 'greenn') {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(pedo)
            }
     })
            
        
      
    
//Removes Roles
    kaoru.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

      
        if (reaction.emoji.name === 'bluee') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(thirteen)
        }
        if (reaction.emoji.name === 'pinkk') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(sixteen)
        }
        if (reaction.emoji.name === 'yelloww') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(legal)
        }
        if (reaction.emoji.name === 'greenn') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(pedo)
        }
    });
}
}
}```
````

Comment: Since you are using `await reaction.fetch();` it should work, are you using the latest version of discord.js ?

Comment: Try fetching the messages you are listening to for reaction adds. The event only emits for cached messages

Comment: Oh yeah, i tried using reaction.fetch but i kinda didn't know how to link it to it correctly. Help would be appreciated, but i can / will try to understand it too